# Как вернуть предыдущее состояние background для div ? Java Script

Tags: javascript, css, функции, html

Существует `div`  у которого значение `backgroundImage="url('img/q1.jpg')"`. После нажатия на `div` происходит смена картинки на hell.jpg.  Вопрос, как при повторном нажатии этого же `div` вернулась предыдущая картинка (q1.jpg)? Т.е как вернуть предыдущее состояние.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

     <style type="text/css">
        .blocks {border: 2px solid red;margin:auto;}
        hr {height: 0px}
        #f1 {border: 1px solid black; margin: 9px; background: url(img/q2.png); width:590px;height: 300px;display: inline-block;}
        #f2{border:1px solid black;margin: 10px;background: url(img/q2.png);width: 590px;height: 300px;display: inline-block;}

        .div{
 background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/pXLmSQU.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat
 width:300px; 
 height:300px;
}

     </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document_testing</title>

    <script src="jstest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>



<!-- Центральное поле -->   <center><p><h1>Hello</h1></p></center>


<div class="blocks">
    <div id="f1">First block</div>
    <div id="f2">Second block</div>

</div>



</body>
</html>






window.addEventListener('load',regEvent,false);

function regEvent(e)


       {


    document.getElementById("f2").addEventListener("click",oClick,false);


      }






function oClick(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById("f2");
  if (element.style.backgroundImageOld) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = element.style.backgroundImageOld; // restore original value
    delete element.style.backgroundImageOld; // clean up for next click
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundImageOld = element.style.backgroundImage; // remember original value
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/hell.jpg')"; // set new value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет чудесного способа сказать диву: "А ну-ка, вернись в свое начальное состояние!"  Раз Вы меняете свойство, то должны запомнить старое значение, если хотите в дальнейшем его восстановить.

```
function oClick(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById("f2");
  if (element.style.backgroundImageOld) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = element.style.backgroundImageOld; // restore original value
    delete element.style.backgroundImageOld; // clean up for next click
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundImageOld = element.style.backgroundImage; // remember original value
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/hell.jpg')"; // set new value
  }
}
```

(Все гораздо проще, если использовать css классы.)

Вот пример работающего кода:

```js
function oClick(e) {
  var element = this;//document.getElementById("f2");
  if (element.style.backgroundColorOld) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = element.style.backgroundColorOld;
    delete element.style.backgroundColorOld;
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundColorOld = element.style.backgroundColor;
    element.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  }
}

document.getElementById("f2").onclick = oClick;
```

```html
<div id="f2" style="background-color:pink;">
It's been a long time that I have been waiting<br/>
For the words you never have said.<br/>
But today my last hope has vanished<br/>
For they say you are going away.<br/>
<br/>
Come and stay by my side, if you love me,<br/>
Do not hasten to bid me adieu.<br/>
And remember the Red River Valley<br/>
And the girl who have loved you so true.<br/>
</div>
```

*Update*

Так у Вас первоначальный фон определен отдельным стилем. Как же это мы не догадались! Вот что Вам нужно:

```
function oClick(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById("f2");
  if (element.style.backgroundImage) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = null; // clean up for next click
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/hell.jpg')"; // set new value
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Это должно было сработать? Если так, то я проверил- не работает. 2)Спасибо за некоторое разъяснение, но причем тут css классы?

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan Вы неправильно скопировали мой код.

Comment: скопировал все что в сером блоке вы указали

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan работает. Проверти пути до картинок.

Comment: Хоть убей не получается, что не так делаю? Меняется картинка, но при повторном нажатии не переходит в предыдущее состояние.  Вот скриншоты  js и HTML :  https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/25/bad6578857d7777e4f1635a36cc05b90-full.png            https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/25/43ebb747fbfc286042dae8949914fbdc-full.png

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan Сейчас.

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan Добавьте, пожалуйста, html и css в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил,  сначала html потом js идет

Comment: "Так у Вас первоначальный фон определен отдельным стилем. Как же это мы не догадались! Вот что Вам нужно:"  - все равно не помогло, обратно не возвращает при повторном нажатии

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan пардон, поправил в последнем фрагменте

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Единственное хотел бы понять на каком шаге в коде система понимает, что нужно вернуть именно прошлую картинку?

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan когда обнаруживает, что явное свойство стиля имеет какое-то значение `if (element.style.backgroundImage) {`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69247/discussion-between-vaagn-akopyan-and-igor).

Comment: Все, разобрался друг, спасибо тебе.  Код проверяет, если есть какое-то значение  в background, то он сбрасывает это значение и переходит в состояние по умолчанию, которая в html прописана. А если видит, что значения нет, то устанавливает картинку hell.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ну как пример можно вот так:

```js
var first = true;

var new_bg ="https://mosthdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cute-And-Beautiful-Asian-Girls-Wallpapers.jpg";
var old_bg = "https://i.imgur.com/pXLmSQU.jpg";
  
window.addEventListener('load', regEvent, false);

function regEvent(e) {
  document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("click", oClick, false);
}

function oClick(e) { 
   if(first){
      document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+new_bg+"')";
   }else{
      document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+old_bg+"')"; 
   }
   first = !first; 
}
```

```css
#div{
 background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/pXLmSQU.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat
 width:300px; 
 height:300px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="div"></div>
```

Если можно то Можно на [Jquery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js):

```js
$('.div').bind('click', bg);
var first = true;

var new_bg ="https://mosthdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cute-And-Beautiful-Asian-Girls-Wallpapers.jpg";
var old_bg = "https://i.imgur.com/pXLmSQU.jpg";

function bg(e) {
    if(first){
      $(this).css({"background-image":"url("+new_bg+")"});
    }else{
      $(this).css({"background-image":"url("+old_bg+")"});
    }
    first = !first;
}
```

```css
.div{
 background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/pXLmSQU.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat
 width:300px; 
 height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div"></div>
```