# Пытаюсь сделать мигания двух картинок наложенных одна на одну

Tags: jquery

У меня проблема в том что я хочу сделать мигания бесконечным, а у меня мигает только  один раз...

```js
var $bomb=$('.bomb');
  var $bomb_light=$('.bomb_light');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $bomb_light.css('display', 'none');
  }, 1000);
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
 }
 .bomb_light {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="" class="bomb">
  <img src="https://1funny.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/laughing-owl.jpg" alt="" class="bomb_light">
 </div>
```

Comment: [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749281/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-background-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-div-java-script/749288#749288)

Answer (score 1):

**setTimeout** - запускает код единожды.

**setInterval** - запускает код постоянно с заданной периодичностью.

```js
 setInterval(function(){
   $('img').toggleClass("bomb");
 }, 1000);
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
.bomb_light {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
  
.bomb{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="" class="bomb">
  <img src="https://1funny.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/laughing-owl.jpg" alt="" class="bomb_light">
</div>
```

Comment: всем по тысяче очков!

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector('.bomb').classList.toggle('bomb_act')
}, 2000);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 230px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.bomb_light {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bomb_act {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" class="bomb">
  <img src="https://1funny.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/laughing-owl.jpg" class="bomb_light">
</div>
```